# Exiting a non void method? (Java)

Tags: methods, exit

I was wonder how you would go about exiting a method early. If this was a void type, I would just do "return", however since this is an int type, it wants me to return an integer. How do I return to main without returning any integers. Thanks.

```
public static int binarysearch(String[] myArray, String target, int first, int last)
{
    int index;

    if  (first > last)
    {
        index = -1;
        System.out.println("That is not in the array");
        // Return to main here
    }
```

Comment: There is only two ways to exit this method, either return an integer or throw an exception.

Comment: Is this an exceptional case? That is, does your method have as part of its contract that first must be <= last? If that is the case, then you might consider throwing an exception here, probably IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 4):

You can't return from a method without a return value, in the traditional sense.

You can either `return -1;` and declare in your documentation that `-1` represents a failed search, or you can throw an [exception](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm). If you throw an exception, though, you'll need to catch it. You can read more about that in the linked article.

Comment: ...unless the exception you throw is a RuntimeException

Comment: That's true, but this is an error that can be expected at compile time, so it shouldn't be a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options....
1. break;
2. return a value that you know would not be returned from a valid result. Eg 99999999 or -34

Those would be simple choices....

Edit
Of course break would only exit the loop. So youd still need to return a known value.

Comment: `break;` will not exit the method. It is used to exit loops.

Comment: True. I meant it could be used to jump out and return a given known value. Admittedly not explained very well.